# Replacing multiple lines using sed

Tags: bash, sed

Good day!

I'm trying to figure out how `hold space` and `pattern space` work in `sed` so I can use it to replace multiple strings.

For example, if you want to replace the first and second lines with `NEW STRING`:

```sh
echo -e "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n"
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

In order to get such a STDOUT:

```sh
NEW STRING
NEW STRING
cc
dd
```

I'm trying to do something like:

```sh
echo -e "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n" | sed -e 'commands'
```

I know it can be done this way:

```sh
echo -e "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd\n" | tr '\n' '\0' | sed -e 's#aa#NEW STRING#;s#bb#NEW STRING#' | tr '\0' '\n'
NEW STRING
NEW STRING
cc
dd
```

But how do you solve this problem without using `tr`?

Can you also suggest a case where we don't know the line numbers? We only know that `aa` comes after `bb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` commands accept a range of lines to operate on:

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" aa bb cc dd | sed '1,2s/.*/NEW STRING/'
NEW STRING
NEW STRING
cc
dd
```

Some like `s` work on individual lines in the range, some treat the whole range as a block to apply the command to:

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" aa bb cc dd | sed '1,2c\
NEW STRING'
NEW STRING
cc
dd
```

---

> For example, one line is aaa, another line is bbb. We know that aaa comes before bbb, but we don't know their numbers in the file.

One approach I threw together (There might be better; and only tested with GNU `sed`)

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" qq rr aa bb cc aa xx dd |
  sed '/^aa$/{N; /^aa\nbb$/{s/.*/NEW STRING\nNEW STRING/; p; d}; P; D}'
qq
rr
NEW STRING
NEW STRING
cc
aa
xx
dd
```

If the current line is *aa*, `N` to appends the next line to the current pattern space. If it's now *aa\nbb*, replace it with two *NEW STRING* lines, print out the pattern space, delete it and start over with a new line. If the pattern space has something else, print out everything up to the first newline, delete that text from the pattern space, and start again with just that second line that was read by `N` in it.

Comment: What if we don't know the line numbers, but we know that we need to replace the lines by a regular expression?

For example, one line is `aaa`, another line is `bbb`. We know that `aaa` comes before `bbb`, but we don't know their numbers in the file. The line `bbb` comes after `aaa`.

Thank you!

Comment: @alex2020: It would be better if you specify these requirements in question itself.

Comment: @alex2020 See edit.

Comment: For last solution perhaps `sed '/^aa/{N;/^bb/M!{P;D};s/.*/new string/p}' file`?

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to experiment with pattern space and hold space, then this would be an example:

```
echo -e "aa\nbb\ncc\ndd" | sed '1{ s/.*/NEW STRING/; h}; 2g'
```

Output:

```
NEW STRING
NEW STRING
cc
dd
```

Replace first line with `NEW STRING` and then copy pattern space to hold space (`h`). In second line copy hold space to pattern space (`g`).